# ReadFile in TextArea JAVA

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readfile

I want the textarea show the content of a file txt. Here is my code, it just shows the last line of the text, I know the problem is `ta1.settext()`. Can someone pls give me some advice?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getSource() == btnOK) {
        String link = tf1.getText().toString();
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(link)))
        {
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                ta1.setText(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }
```

all the line of the file

The last line

Comment: it will show last line that is read from file

Comment: Use `ta1.append(line)` .

Answer (score 1):

you are resetting your TextArea text by the latest line read from your file. While your need is to append all the lines read and show them.

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      ta1.append(line);
}
```